# use repository in custom class laravel

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.8

i´m traying to create and use one personaliced class and use Laravel´s repository. For this, i was created a `UpdateVisualizationsRequest` and `CreateVisualizationRequest` also `VisualizationRepository`. his content it´s:

UpdateVisualizationsRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Models\Visualization;

class UpdateVisualizationRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return Visualization::$rules;
    }
}
```

CreateVisualizationRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Models\Visualization;

class CreateVisualizationRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return Visualization::$rules;
    }
}
```

visualizationRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Visualization;
use Illuminate\Container\Container as Application;
use InfyOm\Generator\Common\BaseRepository;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\CacheableInterface;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\CacheableRepository;

/**
 * Class VisualizationRepository
 * @package App\Repositories
 * @version August 29, 2019, 9:38 pm UTC
 *
 * @method Visualization findWithoutFail($id, $columns = ['*'])
 * @method Visualization find($id, $columns = ['*'])
 * @method Visualization first($columns = ['*'])
 */
class VisualizationRepository extends BaseRepository implements CacheableInterface
{

    use CacheableRepository;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fieldSearchable = [
        'ip',
        'model_type',
        'model_name',
    ];

    /**
     * Configure the Model
     **/
    public function model()
    {
        return Visualization::class;
    }
}
```

in my class i´m traying to create a function to add visualization to my post blog, and increments. My class

```
<?php

namespace App\Custom;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Visualization;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateVisualizationRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateVisualizationRequest;
use App\Repositories\VisualizationRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class VisualizationCustom //extends Controller
{
    /** @var  VisualizationRepository */
    private $visualizationRepository;


    /*public function __construct($visualizationRepo)
    {
        //parent::__construct();
        $this->visualizationRepository = $visualizationRepo;
    }*/

    static function countVisualization($id, $model, $repository){
        
        $data = array(
            "ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            "model_type" => $model,
            "model_id" => $id
        );

        $result = Visualization::where('ip', '=', $data["ip"])->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->first();
        
        if(is_null($result)){
            $visualization = $repository->create($data);
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

this class i´m calling in controller:

```
//insert time when show post
VisualizationCustom::countVisualization($post->id, 'Model\Blog', VisualizationRepository);
```

but always returned for me:

```
Too few arguments to function Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\guiaPaladar\app\Http\Controllers\Web\BlogController.php on line 87 and exactly 1 expected
```

and i don´t understand that i´m doing wrong...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hey, I think you should review the error message more carefully. The issue seems to be that you are calling the BaseRepository constructor without any arguments ([when it requires the `$app` argument](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Eloquent/BaseRepository.php#L93)). Could you show us line 87 of BlogController.php?

Comment: @Howl thanks for your response, it´s in my question in line `//insert time when show post`